# How do I programmatically add an EGeneric Type Argument to an EAttribute?

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

How can I programmatically add an EGeneric Type Argument to an `EAttribute`?
I can create an EAttribute like this:

```
EAttribute eAttribute = EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE.createEAttribute();
eAttribute.setName("myAttribute");
EDataType dataType = EcorePackage.eINSTANCE.getEEList();
// add here String to List as generic argument?
eAttribute.setEType(dataType);
```

But with that code snippet the generic type argument of the `EEList` is not specified. In Eclipse I would fix that with `New Child > EGeneric Type Argument` and then set the `EClassifier` of the EGeneric Type Argument to `EString`. But how can I do that programmatically?

At the end, the attribute should look like this:
[image: EAttribute Tree View]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me some time but I have a solution:

```
EAttribute eAttribute = EcoreFactory.eINSTANCE.createEAttribute();
eAttribute.setName("myAttribute");
eAttribute.setEType(EcorePackage.eINSTANCE.getEEList());
// This is the interesting part:
EGenericType eGenericTypeArgument = ecoreFactory.createEGenericType(); // line 1
eGenericTypeArgument.setEClassifier(EcorePackage.eINSTANCE.getEString()); // line 2
eAttribute.getEGenericType().getETypeArguments().add(eTypeArgument); // line 3
```

1. In **line 1** a new `EGenericType` is created from the `EcoreFactory`. That is our EGeneric Type Argument.
2. Now, in **line 2**, we set the data type of the EGeneric Type Argument to `EString`.
3. In the last step, in **line 3**, we add the EGeneric Type Argument to the `EGenericType` of the `EAttribute` (NOT the `EType` we set earlier).

In hindsight it makes sense that we do not modify the `EDataType`, we rather modifiy the `EAttribute`.